# Convert cell reference to text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to extract data from another sheet in an Excel file. The sheet name is stored in a cell.

This is the equation so far:

```
= INDIRECT("'" & $A$33 & "'!" & "C4")
```

The sheet name is in cell A33, and I want the contents of cell C4 in that sheet.

But I want to drag this to the right and have C4 update to D4, E4 etc. Is there a way to convert C4 to text so it can be used in `INDIRECT`, but also have it update with position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very short answer...

> ... CELL("address",C4)...